# Calculations based on index/offset that incorporates multiple columns in one function

Tags: excel

Here is an example spreadsheet:
[image]

The idea is that one has a monte carlo simulation of Bitcoin prices starting from column `G`. I then calculate the rank of the terminal values (row `7`, columns `H:L`), `1` being the highest price. Based on the rank value set in cell `E1`, I want to calculate the average price of the bitcoin. So if rank is `3`, then I want to take paths that correspond to ranks `3,4,5` -> i.e. column `H,I and L`. And then I want the values in `B2` to = `average(H2,I2,L2)`, in `B3 = average(H3,I3,L3)`, etc.

I couldn't make this work with offsets. Because depending on the `E1` value, you will have a variable number of columns that you want to average. Obviously, I have many more columns in my main spreadsheet. Currently `9000` columns. I would do this in Python, but I have to stick to Excel. How would I achieve my goal?

Thanks

*EDIT*: It does not have to be index/offset. But I just thought that those are probably the function that will help in this case. Rank can be obtained with the =RANK() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you need `AVERAGEIF`, e.g. in cell `B2`:

```
= AVERAGEIF($H$8:$L$8,">="&$E$1,$H2:$L2)
```

(And then drag this formula down to cell `B6`.)

---

**EDIT**

To use more than one condition, you have to use `AVERAGEIFS` instead of `AVERAGEIF`.

E.g., something like this:

```
= AVERAGEIFS($H2:$L2,$H$8:$L$8,">="&$E$1,$H$8:$L$8,"<="& <whatever> )
```

Comment: hey. qq. how do I make a condition that >= and <=. With the AND()?

Comment: hmm AND() doesn't work for this. Like I want to do something like >=4 and <=5 in this example

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal It can be done, but you need `AVERAGEIFS`. See my edit to the question above.